# javascript how to change date now format

Tags: javascript, date, datetime

I am facing an issue with javascript dates. I want to change the format of date

```
        this.setState({ 

          current: Date(Date.now()),



      }, 1000);


//convert minutes 
//if minutes are 0 to 29 then show current hours reset the minutes again start with 0 like 18:00 
//if minutes are 29 to 59 then show current hours reset the minutes again start with 30 like 18:30

var slotTime1 = currentdate.getHours() +':'+ (currentdate.getMinutes() <= 29 ? '00' : '30') ;  //10:30
```

Output:

```
Thu May 14 2020 10:00:30 GMT+0500 (Pakistan Standard Time)
```

Expected

```
10:00:52 AM
```

```
10:30 AM
```

What should I change?

Comment: Use [Intl.DateTimeFormat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/DateTimeFormat/DateTimeFormat).

Comment: When called as a function, *Date* doesn't take any arguments and returns a string representing the current date and time. So in `Date(Date.now())`, the argument is redundant, the expression produces the exact same result as `Date()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use Date [`toLocaleTimeString()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleTimeString) method like:

```js
const current = new Date()
const timestring = current.toLocaleTimeString()
console.log( timestring )   //=> 10:47:52 AM
```

The `toLocaleTimeString()` method returns a string with a language sensitive representation of the time portion of the date.

---

To only get `hh:mm a` format you can pass option object to the `toLocaleTimeString()` method like:

```js
const current = new Date()
const timestring = current.toLocaleTimeString([], { hour: '2-digit', minute: '2-digit' })
console.log( timestring )   //=> 10:50 AM
```

---

With `setState`:

```
this.setState({
  current: new Date().toLocaleTimeString([], { hour: '2-digit', minute: '2-digit' })
});
```

Comment: it is not working i defined in `setState` [@](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1823841/pala%d1%95%d0%bd)

Comment: I have updated the code on how to use with `setState`

Comment: how should i define my `current.toLocaleTimeString()` in setstate [@](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1823841/pala%d1%95%d0%bd)

Comment: Like this: `this.setState({
  current: new Date().toLocaleTimeString([], { hour: '2-digit', minute: '2-digit' })
});`

Comment: you don't understand

Comment: i updated the posts [@](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1823841/pala%d1%95%d0%bd)

Comment: Please don't keep adding multiple questions to the same post. Your main question in this is post is how to get a date in `10:30 AM` format, which is resolved. If you have further questions please create separate questions for it. Thanks!

Comment: ok can you please tell me? [@](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1823841/pala%d1%95%d0%bd)

Answer (score 0):

```
var date=new Date();    
console.log(date.getHours() + ":" + date.getMinutes()+ ":" + date.getSeconds() + " " + date.getHours()<12 ? 'AM' : 'PM'}`);
```

OUTPUT : 11:9:37 AM

**date.getHours()<12 results in AM between 12Am to 11:59 AM and after 11:59 it results in PM**

Comment: `date.getHours() < 12? 'AM' : 'PM'` is a lot less to type and more semantic. Also you should pad the minutes and seconds to two digits. ;-)